# \GuzzleHttp\Client resolving hangs if contextual binding is done using make() or makeWith()

Tags: laravel, guzzle, contextual-binding

I am writing a simple API-wrapper and this wrapper needs the configured GuzzleHttp\Client instance as a dependency.

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class Api {
    private $client;

    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if I create `Client` instance using `new Client()` in `AppServiceProvider->register()`:

```php
$this->app->when(Api::class)
    ->needs(Client::class)
    ->give(function () {
        return new Client(['base_uri' => config('services.api.base_uri')]);
    });
```

But `Api` instance resolving hangs if I create `Client` instance using `make()` or `makeWith()`:

```php
$this->app->when(Api::class)
    ->needs(Client::class)
    ->give(function () {
        return $this->app->makeWith(Client::class, ['config' => ['base_uri' => config('services.api.base_uri')]]);
    });
```

I did fast testing via tinker:

```php
app(\App\Api::class);
```

and it just hangs forever.